# Solve( in tibasic is outputting the wrong answer

Tags: algorithm, solver, ti-basic

If I have a solve command set up in a tibasic script like so:
Solve(A=BC, A, 2), where B=2 and C=5
The Solve( will output 2. To my knowledge the syntax for solve is:
Solve(expression, variable, guess, {lower, upper})sto>variable

I need some help figuring out whether this is an issue with my code, or a fundamental issue with the solve(, and I just need to write an iterative algorithm. Also possibly important is that A=CB is just an example equation, the full program will be using much more complicated programs than the example, and I am also aware that the solve( is not exactly right, because it iterates.

My full code to recreate the issue is:

```
“A=BC”sto>Str1
Str1sto>Y1
5sto>B
2sto>C
Disp solve(Y1,A,2)
```

- I have tried changing the guess, it just accepts any value, like it’s not iterating at all.
- I have tried adding bounds using {} and changing those values
- I have also ran the same values through the interactive menu found in math>C, and it outputs the right answer
- I have tried manually entering the equation instead of just Y1
- I have tried setting the equation = to 0, like “0=BC+A”

In all cases I was expecting to get 10 as an output, but in every occasion the output is always the guess.

Comment: Keep in mind `solve(` finds a root of a function, if you put `A=B` as the equation then it tries to find something that makes that *false* since false is zero and therefore a "root" (kind of). But that's probably not what you meant to do in this case.

Comment: Ok, that’s helpful, but I still don’t understand why if I use the Numeric Solver at the bottom of the math menu, it can solve the equation but the solve( can’t. To explain further what I’m trying to do here, I’m working on a physics program, which stores relevant physics equations, and allows you to use the equations to solve for variables in those equations without having to type out the function in the Numeric Solver